# How to go about saving my custom grid

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable

I've got a DataGridView which has columns that can be renamed by users.  Furthermore, it can be highly manipulated by users such as changing colours of certain fields, and many other custom properties which users can edit themselves (not to mention the actual data itself).

I would like to save the DataGridView when users are ready from editing it - how can I go about doing this? I thought of Serialization, but it does not seem possible to serialize the DataGridView object?

What can be done about this?  It is not practical to keep a reference of each and every property which is changed, or the new names of columns, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serialize a datagridview. 
Implement your own logic to save/load column changes & formats through a configuration file or to a database table.